# two textviews listview android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-search

I have implemented search functionality in my listview which is in my navigation drawer. But currently it has only one textview. I want to be able to add two textviews on the same line without the need of a different class or adapter. Having said that, I still want to be able to search the first textview. So basically my question is : **How do I add two textviews to a row in a listview without using any other class?**

Here's my code:
listitem_row.xml

```
<!-- This is the xml which i use to display one textview on a list row-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

main_activity.xml

```
<!--This is my main activity xml where I have the navigation drawer and the  
listview inside the drawer-->

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Swipe from the left to open the drawer"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-65dp"
    android:background="#111"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textColor="#bfc2d1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:hint="Search" >
    </EditText>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-65dp"
    android:background="#111"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_text"
        android:text="@string/notfound"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffababab"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">
    </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
//This is my mainactivity
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final String[] elename ={"Hydrogen","Helium","Lithium","Beryllium","Boron","Carbon","Nitrogen","Oxygen","Fluorine","Neon","Sodium","Magnesium","Aluminium","Silicon","Phosphorous","Sulphur","Chlorine","Argon","Potassium","Calcium","Scandium","Titanium","Vanadium","Chromium","Manganese","Iron","Cobalt","Nickel","Copper","Zinc","Gallium","Germanium","Arsenic","Selenium","Bromine","Krypton","Rubidium","Strontium","Yttrium","Zirconium","Niobium","Molybdenum","Technetium","Ruthenium","Rhodium","Palladium","Silver","Cadmium","Indium","Tin","Antimony","Tellurium","Iodine","Xenon","Caesium","Barium","Lanthanum","Cerium","Praseodymium","Neodymium","Promethium","Samarium","Europium","gadoliium","Terbium","Dysprosium","Holmium","Erbium","Thulium","Ytterbium","Lutetium","Hafnium","Tantalum","Tungsten","Rhenium","Osmium","Iridium","Platinum","Gold","Mercury","Thallium","Lead","Bismuth","Polonium","Astatine","Radon","Francium","Radium","Actinium","Thorium","Protactinium","Uranium","Neptunium","Plutonium","Americium","Curium","Berkelium","Californium","Einsteinium","Fermium","Mendelevium","Nobelium","Lawrencium","Rutherfordium","Dubnium","Seaborgium","Bohrium","Hassium","Meitnerium","Darmstadtium","Roentgenium","Copernicium","Ununtrium","Ununquadium","Ununpentium","Ununhexium","Ununseptium","Ununoctium"};
final String[] nos = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70","71","72","73","74","75","76","77","78","79","80","81","82","83","84","85","86","87","88","89","90","91","92","93","94","95","96","97","98","99","100","101","102","103","104","105","106","107","108","109","110","111","112","113","114","115","116","117","118"};

//I have already added the String elename to my listview
//and I want to add String nos to it without using any other class. 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //The line below adds the string elename to the listview
    //but using the same line i want to add the string nos if possible.
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem_row,R.id.textView1, elename);
    final EditText searchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbar);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_layout);
    navList.setAdapter(adapter);


    navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){
            //Change view according to numbers

            drawer.closeDrawer(linearLayout);
        }
    });

    //filter list view after search instantly
    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            //The line below removes all the spaces while searching
            String searchedquery = cs.toString().replaceAll(" ","");
            //The line below searches the listview and shows the results
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(searchedquery);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    //hide the keyboard after search on touch list view
    navList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            //The code below hides the keyboard when the user touches the listview
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(navList.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        }
    });

    navList.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
  }
}
```

Comment: add second TextView Right to First TextView. that's it

Comment: @MD I didn't get you. where should i add it?

Comment: add another Textview into your list_item.xml file

Comment: ok.. and how do I put the `String nos` in it?

Comment: He hasn't mentioned how to do that.

Comment: Managing separate ArrayList or Arrays are difficult, instead you should manage a list of POJO.

Comment: You need to create Custom ArrayAdapter. Go to this:[https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/](https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/)

Comment: @Paresh Isn't there any way to this directly from my mainacivity? I mean in the line `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>` itself? cause If I create a new class I will face difficulty in the search part

Comment: @user3234390 you need to stop duplicating your questions. Otherwise you will end u in trouble

Answer (score 2):

For binding two `TextViews` you need to create `Custom Array Adapter`. Go to below links for better understanding:

1. https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView
2. http://prativas.wordpress.com/category/android/custom-listview-in-android-using-custom-arrayadapter/
3. http://jmsliu.com/1390/rss-reader-app-android-tutorial-1-listview-and-arrayadapter.html
4. https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

**Update:**

ListView searching Functionality:

1. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/
2. http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2013/08/04/android-listview-with-searchview/
3. http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/09/custom-listview-alertdialog-with-filter.html
4. http://android-solution-sample.blogspot.in/2011/10/android-search-in-custom-listview.html

Here are the ideas. Go to any links and customized as per your requirement.

Comment: but then how can i perform search on it?

Comment: @user3234390 first of all u create custom adapter and then you can  implement search filter into list for searching. that's it

Comment: Thank you for your help can you please guide me through it? I am not able to understand the code in the links which you provided Can you please simplify it and post it here?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but then how do I put `String nos` in the `textView2`?

Comment: u can use custom adapter